# parallel call multiple bash functions

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have read the example at http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__calling_bash_functions however, is it possible to use gnu parallel to call 2 functions which do not have any variables you pass to them ?

example

```
a() {
  echo "download a"
  wget fileA
}

b() {
  echo "download b"
  wget fileB
}
```

and use parallel to call both functions `a` & `b` ?

Comment: I think that you have to make two different scripts and call them with parallel.

Comment: Instead of using GNU parallel, could  you just call the functions in the background? Like `a &; b` to run `a` concurrently with `b`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run them in background. And then wait for them to complete.

```
a() {
  echo "download a"
  wget fileA
}

b() {
  echo "download b"
  wget fileB
}

a &
b &
wait # waits for all background processes to complete
```

Answer (score 9):

If you insist on using GNU Parallel:

```
a() {
  echo "download a"
  wget fileA
}

b() {
  echo "download b"
  wget fileB
}
export -f a
export -f b
parallel ::: a b
```

If you need read access to variables in the shell you can either export the variables or use `env_parallel`.

Comment: This won't work if your function need to access some variables from the context.